# Keyboard Extension - Find out if user did Copy/Cut/Select

Tags: ios8

In Keyboard Extension, in `UIInputViewController`, I can get notified through `textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput)` of any change, and use `self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBefore/AfterInput` to get current text.

Problem arise when user 'select text'. The 'before' and 'after' "sees" only the part before and after selection.

Is there any way to know if user touched any of the Copy-Cut-Select in a textField (given - we don't have access to that field from Keyboard Extension)?

Something like:

```
if(self.textDocumentProxy.someProperty == UIDocumentProxyTextCut)
```

Or any other way to know which of the `UITextField` action (Copy/Cut/Select) did the user took?

Answer (score 1):

I think we can not find out if user touched on Copy/Cut/Paste menu

> Because a custom keyboard can draw only within the primary view of its
>   UIInputViewController object, it cannot select text. Text selection is
>   under the control of the app that is using the keyboard. **If that app**
>   **provides an editing menu interface (such as for Cut, Copy, and Paste)**,
>   **the keyboard has no access to it**. A custom keyboard cannot offer
>   inline autocorrection controls near the insertion point.

**Source:** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html

P/s:

- I saw `self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextAfterInput` is always `NIL`. Who know why?
- How can we know where the cursor is to provide suggestion for user?

Comment: Not having access to the text field does **not** mean that you cannot be informed. In fact, it is the _same_ text field you have 'no access' to that informs you via delegate that editing did/will occur. Moreover, the `textDocumentProxy` can tell you much more than 'ContextBefore/AfterInput'. Also, `self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextAfterInput` is **not** always `nil`. If you move the courser in mid sentence, you should get the text after it. I do.